# remove stopwords then apply case folding ( how to combine two codes)

Tags: c++, text

I have a txt file called aisha includes this

```
This is a new file I did it for mediu.
Its about Removing stopwords fRom the file
and apply casefolding to it
I Tried doing that many Times
and finally now I could do
```

and I wrote two codes one is to remove some stop words from it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("aisha.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string myArray[200];

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        {
            file >> myArray[i];

            if (myArray[i] !="is" && myArray[i]!="the" && myArray[i]!="that"&& myArray[i]!="it"&& myArray[i]!="to"){
            cout<< myArray[i]<<"  ";
            }



        } 

    }
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

and the other is for apply casefolding for four ketters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("aisha.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file >> std::noskipws;
        char myArray[200];

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        {
            file >> myArray[i];

            if (myArray[i]=='I')
            cout<<"i";
            if (myArray[i]=='A')
            cout<<"a";
            if (myArray[i]=='T')
            cout<<"t";
            if (myArray[i]=='R')
            cout<<"r";
            else 
            if (myArray[i]!='I' && myArray[i]!='T' && myArray[i]!='R')
            cout<<myArray[i];
            }
         file.close();

        }

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

now that I need to combine these two codes into one code that remove stopwords and then apply case folding
the problem that I used `string myArray[200];` for the stopwords codeand `char myArray[200];` for the case folding code 
and I cant use only string or only char
what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the text processors in separate functions and call them one by one in `main`. There will be no names and types collisions.

Here is rough example

```
void removeStopWords(ifstream file) {
    // put your code here for removing the stopwords
}

void applyCaseFolding(ifstream file) {
    // put your code here for applying case folding
}

int main() {
    ifstream file("aisha.txt");
    if(file.is_open()) {
         removeStopWords(file);
         applyCaseFolding(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry can I ask what part to include in each function ?